# server-side sync of outgoing email in MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, server-side-sync, dynamics365-app-outlook

Yes, it can be a stupid question but I cannot validate it as I don't have access to Exchange server.

If I configured Server-Side synchronization in CRM side & then I send email to one of the Contact's email id from Outlook which has doesn't have CRM outlook client installed then would be the outgoing email create an email activity/Sync email in CRM?

I think incoming emails will get synced with CRM server & create email activities as it's server-side synchronization but I really have a doubt on what will happen to outgoing email from Outlook.

I know Dynamics CRM 365 outlook app can sync seamlessly after Server-side sync but I am not sure about this.

I am using Dynamics CRM 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is an option that should be set by each user due to privacy. 
It can be set by going to the personal options tab then go to the Email tab.

Then set the Track option to track all messages.